# Ошибка Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта при попытке удаления строки из БД

Tags: c#, база-данных

Пишу приложение на C#. Пытаюсь удалить строку из БД следующим образом

```
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand deletecomand = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Complaint1 where complaint_id ='" + int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Запись удалена");`
```

При нажатии кнопки появляется ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." Значение индекса точное. Заранее прошу прощения за возможную легкость вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не создали объект, на который ссылается переменная `cmd`. Вероятно, перепутали `cmd` и `deletecomand`. Не забудьте установить команде соединение.